# What to do with runtime generated data spanning several classes?

Tags: python, rest, class, design-patterns, runtime

I'm a self-taught programmer and a lot of the problems I encounter come from a lack of formal education (and often also experience).

My question it the following: How to rationalize where you store the data a class or function creates? I'll make a simple example:

**Case:** I have a webshop (SHOP) with a REST api and a product provider (PROVIDER) also with a REST API. I determine the product, I send that data to PROVIDER who sends me back formatted data that can be read by SHOP to make a working product on the webshop. PROVIDER also has a secondary REST api that provides generated images.

**What I would come up with:**
I'd make three classes: `ProductBase`, `Shop` and `Provider`
`ProductBase` would be the class from where I instantiate and store the individual product information.
`Shop` would be where I design the api interactions with the webshop.
`Provider` same as shop, but for interactions with provider api.

**My problem:** At some point you're creating data that's not clearly separated in concern. For example: Would I store the generated product data (from PROVIDER) in the `ProductBase` instance I created? It feels like I'm coupling the two classes this way. But it not there, then where?
What if I create product images with PROVIDER and I upload them to SHOP? Do I store the uploaded image-url in PRODUCT? How do you keep track of all this info?

**The question I want answered:**
I've read a lot on OOP and Design Patterns, and I have adopted a TDD approach which has greatly helped to improve my code but I haven't found anything on how to approach the flow of at runtime generated data within software engineering.

What would be a good way to solve above problem(s) and could you explain your rationale for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think your current concern is that you have "raw" product data, which you want to store in objects, and you have "processed" (formatted) product data, which you also want to store in objects. Your question being should you mix them.

Let me just first point out the other obvious option. Namely, having two product classes: RawProduct and ProcessedProduct. Which to do?

(Edit: also, to be sure, product data should not be stored in provider. The provide performs the action of formatting but the data is product data. Not provider data).

It depends. There are a couple of considerations:

1) In general, in OOP, the idea is to couple actions on data with the data. So if possible, you have some method in ProductBase like "format()", where format will send the object off to the API to get formatted, and store the result in an instance variable. You can then also have a method like "find_image", that goes and fetches the image url from the API and then stores that in a field. An object's data is meant to be dynamic. It is meant to be altered by object methods.

2) If you need version control (if you want the full history of the object's state to be available), then you can't override fields with new data. So either you need to store a history of every object field in the object, or you need to create new objects.

3) Is RAM a concern? I sometimes create dataclasses that store only the final part of an object's life so that I can fit more of the objects into memory.

Personally I often find myself creating "RawObject" and "ProcessedObject" classes, it's just easier a lot of the time. But that's probably because I mostly work with document processing, so it's very clear. Usually You'll just update the objects data.

A benefit of having one object with the full history is that it is much easier to debug. Because the raw data and the API result are in the same object. So you can very easily probe what went wrong. If you start splitting things up it's harder to track. In general, the more information an object has about where it's been, the easier it is to figure out what went wrong with it.

Remember also though, since this is a Python question, Python is multi-paridigm. And if you're writing pipeline-style architectures (synchronous, linear processes), then a functional approach can also work well.

Once your data is stored in a product object, anything can hold a reference to that. So a shop can reference an object and a product can reference the object. Be clear on the difference between "has-a" relationships and "is-a" relationships.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I think I was a bit anxious to just load the product object with LOADS of data, but as my applications grow in complexity, this is something that probably just happens. I can cut it up into multiple objects anytime I can separate concerns.

Comment: Yes you can do that, or create child objects. If an object has too many instance variables, group some of them into new objects. For example, if you product has pricing information, availabilty information etc, create a pricing object and availability object. But yes, a good rule of thumb is not to create things until you need them, provided that it is easy to create them later if you need to.